# ¿Cómo subir un archivo que se encuentra dentro de una carpeta en github?

Tags: git, github

Estoy intentando enviar a mi repositorio un archivo que se encuentra dentro de una carpeta como se muestra en la imagen de abajo.

Utilizo el comando `git add dist/index.html` pero cuando hago el `git push` en mi repositorio aparece la carpeta `dist` en primer plano. ¿Cómo hago para que suba solamente el archivo que esta dentro?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué y cómo agregas tu archivo al commit?

Comment: hago este proceso => git add dist/index.html => git commit -m "mensaje" => git push origin master

Comment: Antes de preguntar algo mas, puedes mencionar cual es la raiz de tu repositorio? Esto a proposito de clarificar que tus archivos subidos toman la estructura de directorios (o carpetas) que tengas especificada en tu repositorio local dependiendo de donde este localizado tu .git

Comment: También verifica si tienes esa carpeta en el gitignore. Y también necesitamos saber en qué rama estás ahora. Si estás en una distinta a máster el `git push origin master` no hará nada

Comment: No puedes hacer lo que dices, git preserva la estructura de carpetas de tu working dir local. Si quieres que index.html se añada fuera de la carpeta dist, debes tenerlo fuera de esa carpeta en tu working dir.